# How do I create an AAR in Android Studio with Prefab exports?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, aar

I have an Android project for a library (using the `com.android.library` plugin), that includes C++ code.  When I run the `assemble` task in gradle, the outputted AAR contains the native library in the /jni folder.  However, there is no "prefab" folder.  The only documentation I can find about creating Android libraries is here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

The bottom section suggests that the /prefab folder should be there.

I can find information on how to set up a project to *import* prefabs from an AAR, but I can't find any information on how to *build* an AAR with prefab exports.  Is there a way to set up an Android project with gradle to do this?  Are there settings I have to add to specify which native libraries should be exposed?

I'm using Android Studio 4.1.1, gradle 6.8, and Android gradle plugin 4.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered by the samples. Not sure where it is in the docs, they definitely used to be on DAC. https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/prefab/prefab-publishing